# Rethinkdb query to fetch data between 2 epoch times

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I'm trying to run a ReQL query to fetch the data between 2 epoch times, i have a field called "lastUpdatedDttm" using which i'm trying to run the query like below. The lastUpdatedDttm field type is "number" and is just new date().getTime()

```
r.db('my_db').table('my_table').getAll('/mypath', { 
index: 'path' }) .filter(r.row('updatedBy').eq('id').and(r.row('lastUpdatedDttm').during(1512864000000, 1513209600000)))
```

The above query returns error, e: Not a TIME pseudotype:

Am i missing something in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe duration needs time objects as arguments so you need to use the `epochTime` method to convert your times, so

```
r.db('my_db').table('my_table').getAll('/mypath', { index: 'path' })
  .filter(
    r.row('updatedBy').eq(id)
      .and(
        r.row('lastUpdatedDttm')
          .during(
            r.epochTime(1512864000000 / 1000),
            r.epochTime(1513209600000 / 1000)
          )
      )
    )
```

you should also make sure `lastUpdatedDttm` is stored as a date

if you are storing `lastUpdatedDttm` as a number generated by `new Date().getTime()` you can do

```
r.db('my_db').table('my_table').getAll('/mypath', { index: 'path' })
  .filter(record => {
    return record('updatedBy').eq(id).and(
      r.epochTime(record('lastUpdatedDttm').div(1000))
        .during(
          r.epochTime(1512864000000 / 1000),
          r.epochTime(1513209600000 / 1000)
        )
    )
})
```

Comment: still no luck, getting the same error e: Not a TIME pseudotype:, the lastUpdatedDttm type is type.number() and is stored as new Date().getTime()

Comment: new Date().getTime() is not a date, its a number. If you want to store the current date in the database you should be using database time with `r.now()` otherwise you need to store it with `r.epochTime(new Date().getTime())` or shorter `r.epochTime(Date.now())`

Comment: got you, as you said earlier, '.during' only accepts time objects whereas when i run the query using '.gt(1512864000000)' it returns just fine.

Comment: tried the query like below using .gt, r.db('my_db')
  .table('my_table')
  .getAll('/mypath', { index: 'path' })
  .filter(
    r.row('updatedBy')
      .eq('id')
      .and(
        r.row('lastUpdatedDttm')
          .gt(1512864000000)
      )
  )

Comment: see my updated answer where the unix times are converted